# Why is my js only works on the first iteration in @foreach?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I'm displaying all data in a table form using @foreach. The javascript that's been called on keyup() only works on the first iteration.

I'm trying to add all columns and all rows.

```
@foreach ( $data as $row )
<tr class="table-mgt">
 <td>
    <input id="txtFirstNo" type="number" value="{{$row->feb_p }}" 
     onkeyup="sum()" />
    <input id="txtSecondNo"  type="number" value="{{$row->feb_a }}" disabled 
     />
    <input id="txtResult"  type="number" value="{{$row->feb_p - $row->feb_a  
     }}" disabled /> </td>

 <td>
    <input id="txtFirstNo" type="number" value="{{$row->mar_p }}" 
     onkeyup="**sum()**" />
    <input id="txtSecondNo"  type="number" value="{{$row->mar_a }}" disabled/>
    <input id="txtResult"  type="number" value="{{$row->mar_p - $row->mar_a 
     }}" disabled/> </td>

 and so on.. and so forth...(until dec_*)
@endforeach

<script type="text/javascript">
   function sum() {
       var txtFirstNo = document.getElementById('txtFirstNo').value;
       var txtSecondNo = document.getElementById('txtSecondNo').value;
       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNo) - parseInt(txtSecondNo);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('txtResult').value = result;
       }
    }
</script>
```

The javascript only works on feb. It doesn't work for march to december.

Comment: It's because you have added id which should be different for each elements. Secondly you should specify node like parent or something so you can get and assign values within single parent element when you use class instead of id

Comment: You're generating multiple html elements with the same id, so document.getElementById won't work.

Comment: The output looks like this: https://ibb.co/yBxKrZ7

Answer (score 0):

You set same id for multiple elements. Elements id must be unique, so javascript looks only for one element and don't check other elements. Change id to class and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, it still doesn't work for me. Maybe my code doesn't work.